# using jquery, how can I extend and pass an object to a function right at function call?

Tags: jquery, function, extend

How can I do this in one line?

```
var myOptions = defaultOptions;
$.extend(myOptions, {width: 200});
$("#myField").foo(myOptions);
```

I dont want to make any changes to defaultOptions.
I do not need myOptions anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newSettings = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, { width: 200 });
$('#myfield').foo(newSettings);
```

Or

```
$('#myfield').foo($.extend({}, defaultOptions, { width: 200 }));
```